# How to design walkthrough slides?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, walkthrough, screen-density

I had made few walkthroughs for my app in illustrator and put it in the drawable folder in the project. For experimenting I put one of the images(with 600px x 1100px ) in xhdpi folder in my drawable and tried on my oneplus x (xhdpi) and it looks fine. But when I scaled it to hdpi(1,5) and xxhdpi(2,5)  the image has blank spaces in the flanks!

How can I make the image fill the whole screen on all devices?
I've been trying for couple of days now but still nothing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: set scale type centerCrop may be fix your problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35079241/increase-the-size-of-image-in-android-app/35080006#35080006

Comment: it's not possible to do that because I'm using a viewpager and the images are from the drawable photo, so there's no xml file.

Comment: put ImageView inside of your **viewPager** also put some part of code to help you better ;)